# Django admin site: how to compute field from multiple fields value?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-forms

I am wondering if is there a way to compute a field in the admin site based on a concatenation of multiple fields.

Basically I have a Product model with different fields associated to various attributes 
(colour, size, length etc).

I would like to compute the code value to be a concatenation of the values of the various attribute fields like:

```
code = colour + "_" + size + "_" + length
```

Comment: This is a bit vague. When do you want to compute it? On display? Do you want to save the computed value in the database?

Comment: hey. sorry for the vagueness, Im at the very beginning of it :) the ideal would be for it to be computed dynamically on display like in the auto-populate. for sure it has to be saved. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to do this. I've done things like this in my models' `clean` method:

```
def Product(models.Model)
    # field definitions here

    def clean(self):
        self.code = self.colour + "_" + self.size + "_" + self.length
```

Doing it in the model layer (which will only work on versions of [Django 1.2 and above](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.2/#model-validation)) has the advantage that it'll be applied everywhere, not just where you use a particular form.

Comment: doesnt seem to work: it throws an error of the type "instance needs to have a primary key value before a many-to-many relationship can be used.". String concatenation also doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

look at ModelAdmin.prepopulated_fields